# Which fighter jet is seen here at Centennial Airport Colorado?

Tags: military, aircraft-identification, fighter

These fighter jets landed at Centennial Airport Colorado today. What type of fighter jet are they?[image]

Answer (score 24):

These are [F-18E Super Hornets](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_F/A-18E/F_Super_Hornet), the single seat variant of the E/F Super Hornet.

The E/F variants are most noticeably different than their C/D counterparts by the square air intakes. When they are side-by-side the size difference is probably more noticeable.

Comment: The other thing I always look for is the little vertical stabilizers/fins ("fences") near the front of the wing in the non-Super Hornets: [pic on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:An_F-A-18C_Hornet_launches_from_the_flight_deck_of_the_conventionally_powered_aircraft_carrier.jpg). They're easier for me to remember, because they come with a story: the Hornet originally didn't have them, but field testing revealed vortices that would hit the tail stabilizers and damage them; the small fins fixed that. When they redesigned the Super, they took the vortexes into account from the start.